# Python, code repeating itself til a certain event

Tags: python

I have made a little game where you kill the Orc. You choose to attack or heal, etc. I am new to python. I can't seem to make the code loop so it goes until the orc or you die. Any solutions/tips?

```
from time import sleep
from random import randint
#here
game = True
health = 100
feeling_brave = True
playerturn = True
attackdmg = randint(2,4)
maxhealth = health
heal = randint(3,5)
playerab = 0
ahealth = randint(10,70)
amaxhealth = ahealth
attackadmg = randint(1,3)
orcturn = False


sssprint('Kill the orc! He has', (ahealth), ('health. '))
sleep(1)

while game == True:

    if playerturn == True:
        playerab = input('Attack or Heal? ')

        if playerab == ('Attack'):
            sleep(1)
            print('You decide to attack the Orc.')
            sleep(1)
            ahealth = ahealth - attackdmg
            print('You hit the orc for', (attackdmg))
            sleep(1)
            print('The Orc has', (ahealth), ('health remaining.'))
            orcturn = True
            playerturn = False

    if playerab == ('Heal') and health != maxhealth and playerturn == True:
        print('You cast a healing spell on yourself')



    if orcturn == True:
         sleep(1)
         print('Its the orcs turn to strike!')
         if ahealth > 9:
             sleep(1)
             health =  health - attackadmg
             print('The orc strikes you for', (attackadmg))
             print('You have', (health), 'health left')
             orcturn = False
             splayerturn = True
```

Any help will be nice :D

Comment: What's the problem of your code during execution? By the way, why putting `if playerab == ('Heal')` outside the player turns?

Comment: Thank you @MatrixTai I fixed that. My error is that it only plays through once then it stops

Answer (score 0):

Fixed lol there was a s before the playerturn variable! I am an idiot lol